# Add HTML to a textView in a ListView

Tags: android, html, listview, hyperlink

HI I have a question I can't seem to figure out. I am trying to add HTML to a textView that is a column in a ListView. I have a 3 coulmn row for a ListView.

My code to add the html to a textView is:

```
TextView mTextSample = new TextView(this);
String text = "Visit my <a href='http://www.newblog.com'>blog</a>";
mTextSample.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Then I have a HashMap in which I add mTextSample.getText() too:

```
HashMap Object, Object map = new HashMap Object, Object();              
map.put("c1", "STATUTE");
map.put("c0", "");
map.put("c2", mTextSample.getText()); 
mylist.add(map);
```

Then this row is added to my ListView (R.id.CELL2 should have the html in it):

```
final ListView listnew = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvdata);

SimpleAdapter mSchedulenew = new SimpleAdapter(this, (List<? extends Map<String, ?>>) mylist, R.layout.row, 
new String[] {"c1","c0","c2"}, new int[] {R.id.CELL1,R.id.CELLBlank, R.id.CELL2}); 
listnew.setAdapter(mSchedulenew);
```

But when run only the "Visit my blog" is displayed (which is correct but no link is generated). It seems like the html is being filter out when I add this row to the listView.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it -

```
TextView mTextSample = new TextView(this);
mTextSample.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

String text = "Visit my <a href='http://www.newblog.com'>blog</a>";
mTextSample.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```